# View API data with chrome DevTools

Tags: api, paypal, network-programming, google-chrome-devtools, paypal-sandbox

I am working on a site that uses the PayPal API. This new site will replace the old site at my job. As of right now, I need to check what data the old site sent to the PayPal API. Is there a way to check what data is being sent to and from a different site or API? It is data that is not typed in by the user, but data that already exists in the database that is being sent to the API.

Any help or advice would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It "depends". On Windows platform you could use:

- [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or;
- [Microsoft Message Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226)

to inspect traffic i/o (on the client *system* where either tool is installed). I'm sure other platforms will have similar tools.

Chrome Dev (or any other browser) tool will help with *browser* based traffic.

IMHO, depending on how "old" the existing system is, it maybe worth looking at the API again to see if any newer features are worth the effort since you're updating things...and seems to me *getting paid/payments systems/ops* would be something high on the priority list :)

Hth...

Comment: I'm not sure if a traffic inspector would help. PayPal API calls are done between the seller's server and PayPal server, and a buyer's machine is not within this traffic path.

Comment: @golddc Yup, that's why I stated _"on the client system where either tool is installed"_ . There wouldn't be any other way to inspect system level traffic (aka "server side" calls) - well not really (network level inspector, but that's probably beyond scope). Browser dev tools can only inspect browser traffic (POST, GET, AJAX, etc.)  it sends/receives - it will not have any insight to server traffic between server A and server B.